# String values are passed as null in postgress in Spring boot using spring data jpa

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

This is a simple spring boot CRUD operation application where the values are not getting saved in postgres.
DepartmentController.java

```
import java.util.List;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.CrossOrigin;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.avinash.dev.departmentservice.model.Department;
import com.avinash.dev.departmentservice.service.DepartmentService;

@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:8081")
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/v1")
public class DepartmentController {

@Autowired
private DepartmentService service;

@GetMapping("/departments")
public List<Department> getAllDepartments(){
    return service.getAllDepartments();
}

@PostMapping("/department")
public Department createDepartment(@RequestBody Department department) {
    return service.saveDepartment(department);
}
```

}

**Department.java**

```
import jakarta.persistence.Column;
import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import jakarta.persistence.GenerationType;
import jakarta.persistence.Table;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "departments")
public class Department {

@jakarta.persistence.Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "department_id")
private Long Id;

@Column(name = "department_name")
private String departmentName; 
//private List<Employee> employeesInDepartment = new ArrayList<>();
```

}
**DepartmentRepository.java**

```
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.avinash.dev.departmentservice.model.Department;

@Repository
public interface DepartmentRepository extends JpaRepository<Department, Long>{
```

}

**DepartmentService.java**

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.avinash.dev.departmentservice.model.Department;
import com.avinash.dev.departmentservice.repository.DepartmentRepository;

@Service
public class DepartmentService {

@Autowired
private DepartmentRepository repository; 

public Department saveDepartment(Department department) {
    return repository.save(department);
}

public List<Department> getAllDepartments() {
    return repository.findAll();
    
}

public Optional<Department> getDepartmentById(Long id) {
    return repository.findById(id);
}
```

}
**application.yml**

```
#server:
  #port: 8081  

spring:
  application:
    name: department-service
  config:
    import:
    - "optional:configserver:http://localhost:8088"

#eureka:
  #client:
    #service-url:
      #defaultZone: http://localhost:8761/eureka

datasource:
  url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres
  username: postgres
  password: ******
```

jpa:
show-sql: true
hibernate:
ddl-auto: update
properties:
hibernate.dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect

I am making a POST request via post man. But only the id is save. the name is being saved as `null`. The entity is going as `null` when i debug the code. The `departmentName` is going as `null`. The log is here :

```
Hibernate: insert into departments (department_name) values (?).
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

**POST : http://localhost:8081/api/v1/department**
{
departmentName:"IT"
}

Comment: For starters don't use `@Data` with JPA entities (https://deinum.biz/2019-02-13-Lombok-Data-Ojects-Arent-Entities/ on the why). Next your JSON is wrong, the field name should be in quotes. `"departmentName" : "IT"` so what you are sending is invalid  JSON to start with.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. JSON is in quotes but while posting my query it somehow was removed. Sorry for the same. I will check for @data annotation if that makes any change.

Comment: removing @Data is also not helping either.

Answer (score 1):

1. You should separate between the DTO and request object. The request object wont include id for example.
2. Use request validation with `@valid` annotation to make sure you push back bad requests.

   ```
   public class DepartmentRequest {
      @NotBlank(message="error message in case name is null or blank")           
      private String name; 
   }
   ```

Then if is valid convert to Database entity and save in Postgres

Comment: The DTO pattern is a good practice but I don't know why this is not working. I have seen may tutorials where they use entity as transfer object which gets saved in DB. The ID is saved but the department name is going as null.

Comment: There is similar thread but the solution which is suggested I am doing that here. : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73057742/java-springboot-posting-to-postgresql-results-in-null-values

Comment: Whats wrong to work in best practices? What about the request validations? Did you see the departmentName not null in Controller?

Comment: Tried nullable=false but that doesn't affect.

Comment: did you debug this flow? Did you get the correct name in controller?

Comment: yes i debugged. The name is coming correctly.